# Predicting the POS tag of the upcoming word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is there a way in python (by using NLTK or SpaCy or any other library) that I can predict the POS tag of the word that are likely to follow the words so far I have entered.

Eg- If i input

> I am going to

It shows the POS tag of the next most likely word

eg NN, becuase college can come after this

Comment: You can try some machine learning technique; you won't know if it's possible until you try.

Answer (score 2):

You may train a simple language model on POS tag data using LSTMs. That is, say, using Spacy, convert your corpus to POS tag corpus. Train the model using the new corpus. Predict the POS on evaluation. Another way to do it is by building a language model on your data, generate the next word and find its POS.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to familiarize yourself with CoNNL-U Format.
http://universaldependencies.org/format.html

And possibly also UDPipe
https://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe/